# I lose my commit when changes origin branch locally

Tags: git, branch

My operation is :

1. git pull
2. git checkout origin/a
3. changes some code
4. git add.
5. git commit -m "fix: save my changes"
6. git checkout b
7. git checkout origin/a

and I found my changes disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

When you checkout (using [`git switch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309) by the way) `origin/a`, you are in [detached head mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309).

You should:

- `git switch a` to create a local branch `a` linked to `origin/a`
- `git branch -avv` to check a exists, and has origin/a as upstream
- `git reflog` to find the commit you have done
- `git cherry-pick <sha1>` to get that commit on your branch `a`

Comment: @ZhenchuanRen Great! Don't forget to read https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc?tab=answers